# SharePoint 2013 Document Library by using OpenBinaryDirect method I got remote server 401 unauthorized error?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When I am retrieving the file from SharePoint 2013 Document Library by using OpenBinaryDirect method I got remote server 401 unauthorized  error? Could you please help me how to rectify the problum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide online-credentials by using 
SharePointOnlineCredentials(username,password) class in your code

Code:

string username="xxx";

string password="xx";

SecureString ss=new SecureString();

foreach(char c in password)
ss.AppendChar(c)

clientcontext.credentials = SharePointOnlineCredentials(username,ss);

Web web = clientContext.Web;

List list = web.Lists.GetById(new Guid("xxxxxxxxxx"));

var data = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = "query" };

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items_attachments = list.GetItems(data);

clientContext.Load(items_attachments);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listitem in items_attachments)
{

clientContext.Load(listitem, i => i.File);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var fileRef = listitem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;

FileInformation fileinfo =         Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);

Stream fl = fileinfo.Stream;

byte[] s = ReadFully(fl);

}

public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```