# Download from SharePoint Document Library without having user login

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying to download a file from Sharepoint document library from an ASP.NET application. I was able to get a list of files but when I use the same context to download, I got a (401) Unauthorized error. The problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069686/sharepoint-2013-document-library-by-using-openbinarydirect-method-i-got-remote-s) but since I'm trying to download a file without having the user sign in, there are no username and password.
My code is as followed:

```
using (var ctx = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("url"), TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken) )
{                
    var web = ctx.Web;

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fromLocation);

    ctx.Load(file);

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By getting the stream from the file. I was able to convert it to a byte array and call a binary write on it without having to use OpenBinaryDirect and deal with the authentication issue

```
using (var ctx = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("url"), TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken) )
{                
    var web = ctx.Web;

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fromLocation);
    ClientResult(Of Stream) data = file.OpenBinaryStream();

    ctx.Load(file);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();


    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(file.Name);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + file.Name);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", data.Value.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(StreamToByteArray(data.Value));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
}


private byte[] StreamToByteArray(ByVal input As Stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    { 
        int read; 
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        { 
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        } 
        return ms.ToArray();
    } 
}
```

One problem I have with this though is for large file. Using OpenBinaryStream instead of OpenBinaryDirect means that it will take a while to load the file before downloading can begin.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using a Provider Hosted App, if yes, did you set the app permissions to read from the specified document library?

You can also, check the ULS logs and search for the 401 text to see what is the wrong with the identity that tries to download the document